# iOS CoreData entity return as Null after clear the Database

Tags: ios, iphone, database, core-data, applet

When user logout the app, I need to delete the entity from core data, it returns the "null" entity

so i am getting the crash when logout the app, is there any guess for handling the null on entity,

because I have used the following case, but it won't work

```
if(![user isKindOfClass: [NSNull class]]) {
}
```

after delete the entity it return as

```
<user: 0x1c4293ce0> (entity: <null>; id: 0xd000000000040004 <x-coredata://9E21A585-096A-408F-AF0F-CB027A3E48F0/user/p1> ; data: <fault>)
```

[image][image]

can anyone clarify why it happen

Comment: Post the code where you're getting the crash and the error message associated with it.

Comment: I have updated the exact crash , check it

Comment: After you delete the object you should explicitly discard the reference to it by assigning `nil` to `user` and check for `nil` in your `if`. `NSNull` is a singleton object that can be used for putting "null" values into objects that can't hold `nil` references (e.g. `NSArray`)

Answer (score 3):

Your `user` variable still holds a reference to a (deleted) `NSManagedObject` subclass instance.

As the object has been deleted, its `entity` shows as "null" but `user` does not hold a reference to the `NSNull` singleton.

NSNull is a singleton object that can be used for putting "null" values into objects that can't hold nil references (e.g. NSArray)

After you delete your object you should explicitly set `user = nil` and then check for `nil` in your `if`.

```
if (user != nil) {
    [userComtext performBlock: ^{
        user.latitude = latitude
        user.longitude = longitude
    }];
}
```

Comment: still getting the same error only @Paulw11

if (user != nil) {
                      
                      [userContext performBlock: ^{
                        user.lattitude = latitude;
                        user.longitude = longitude;

Comment: Are you sure you are setting `user = nil` when you delete the object? Can you show that code?

Comment: You should edit your question to put that code in it, but is that `user` the same variable you are referring to in the other code in your question?